# Angular - ng-bootstrap - NgbModal Popup windowClass property is not working

Tags: css, angular, twitter-bootstrap, typescript, ng-bootstrap

I have a Modal popup , i want to increase the width of it.

here is angular code

```
openTaskDetails(content) {
const options : NgbModalOptions={
  size : 'lg',
  windowClass :'mycustomClass'
}
this.modalService.open(content ,options).result.then((result) => {
  this.saveTask(result);
}, (reason) => {
  console.log(reason);
});
}
```

and the css is

```
.mycustomClass .modal-lg {
      width : 80% !important;
      max-width: 90% !important;
      background-color:red;
}
```

size property is working fine but windowClass is not.
i tried

```
.mycustomClass {
       width : 80% !important;
       max-width: 90% !important;
       background-color:red;
}
```

but same problem still exist , the width of popup is not increased.

when i inspect element , i see the class name mycustomClass inserted within the HTML but the css is not found.

Comment: you did inlcude the bootstrap.css in index.html or angular.json, right?

Comment: sorry what do you mean ?

Comment: You need add encapsulation:ViewEncapsulation.None in your component. https://angular.io/api/core/ViewEncapsulation

Comment: Elisio , wow , worked,  should i add this option to all components , 
please post your answer so i can mark it as answer

Comment: the default value is Emulated , why it doesn't work with this option

Answer (score -1):

please insert option in modal html like below:

Comment: <div class="{{ options?.windowClass }}">

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Totally unclear, what if the configuration object is directly declared as parameter of method open?